# Running two instances of "docker-compose up"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I run `docker-compose up`, and then after a few seconds I open another terminal window to the same directory and run it again, will I get two separate instances of the container?

Or will the second one attach to the already-running container from the first one?

I can post my `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` if needed.

Comment: You can't have two Docker containers with the same name, and you also can't expose two Docker containers on the same port. I'd wager that you've got at *least* the port hard-coded, so when the second one fires up, it would see that the port is already in use. Assuming you randomise the name and port, you can likely get away with it, though I wouldn't recommend it. The real question is why you're trying to run the same container twice? Is this purely hypothetical, or do you have a specific use case?

Comment: @ObsidianAge The containerized application accesses a database and I'm trying to debug some concurrency issues.  I figured running two copies would be a good tactic.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple instances of service in docker-compose via the `docker-compose up --scale SERVICE=NUM` command documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

For example if you have a docker-compose.yml file with 2 services defined, named `nginx` and `mysql` and you want to run 3 instances of the `nginx` container, you would run the following command:

```
docker-compose up --scale nginx=3
```